# response change on every GET request in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, load-balancing

I am trying to implement a load balance in Django using a round-robin technique by getting a different response on every `GET` call.

My Model:

```
class Load_Balancing(models.Model):
    instance_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
    algorithm = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have tried:

```
class Get_Instance(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        next_instance = Load_Balancing.objects.all().order_by("last_visited")[:1]  # get the oldest one
        next_instance.save()
        data = {}
        for r in ins:
            data["instance_name"] = r.instance_name
        return Response(data)
```

Here `instance_name` is random `URL` and I'm trying to make it dynamic so that on every GET request I get the last instance and then other instances in order i.e the 1st  instance in the database and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `models.DateTimeField()` field instead. Record the last time they were used, then get the oldest one:

```
class Load_Balancing(models.Model):
    ...
    last_visited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...
```

```
class Get_Instance(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        next_instance = Load_Balancing.objects.all().order_by("last_visited").first()  # get the oldest one
        next_instance.save()  # this will update the last_visited field
        ...
```

If you want to get all of the instances:

```
class Get_Instance(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        instances = list(Load_Balancing.objects.all().order_by("-last_visited"))
        current_instance = instances[-1]
        current_instance.save()
        data = []
        for instance in instances:
            data.append({
                'instance_name': instance.instance_name,
                'is_current': instance == current_instance
            })
        return Response(data)
```

This isn't necessarily thread-safe, but unless you need it to be, this should suffice with what you are trying to do

Comment: I am getting an error that "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save' " @GrandPhuba

Comment: and besides that, I want the latest one first and then the oldest one @GrandPhuba

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to get just one load balancer or multiple?

Comment: Did you find the mistake @GrandPhuba

Comment: I want to get the latest instance_name when I call 1st time GET request and then the oldest one and so on.

Comment: Did you get what I'm trying to do @GrandPhuba

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am getting 2 instances at a time @GrandPhuba and can you explain what are we doing here?

Comment: How many load balancers do you have in your db, and do you just want the current one, all of it, or just the first and last one? If you want the current load balancer, my first code should work. If you want to get all of them at once, use the second code.

Comment: I want all of them but one at a time. and currently, I have 3 data in my database. The second code is working fine its just giving 2 data at a time.

Comment: And also can you please explain the code if possible?

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer again. Let me know if that works and if it is, which part needs explaining

Comment: "other_instance_data" is unresolved, so I made it data.append but returning empty list.

Comment: Sorry been replying on my phone. Updated answer again. @zodiac

Comment: Thank you @GrandPhuba